# If-statement inside foreach, the statement is not applying

Tags: php, json, if-statement, foreach

I'm processing a json from an url and showing some data. The problem is that I just want to display two accounts with certain id's but when I execute the following code is echoing the name of each account and not selecting the ones I choosen in the if-statement.

```
foreach ($data as $row) {

    $id = $row->id;
    $account = $row->account;
    $time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    if ($id = 100) {echo $account;}
    elseif ($id = 120) {echo $account;}
    else {}

}
```

The Json is like

```
{"id":120,"Name":"Companytest"},
{"id":121,"Name":"BensonTillis"},
{"id":123,"Name":"JSBrothers"}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use == instead of = in your if statements.

When you are comparing numbers you need to use "==" as it is one of the comparison operators http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

The single "=" is an assigment operator and sets $id to the value on the right hand side. http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php

Comment: While it's correct (and the question is a duplicate), you should elaborate *why* double equality is needed over single equality, not just "You need it".

Comment: @Qirel OK, edited with an explanation of comparison and assignment operators.

Comment: Thank you!!!!....newby mistake

Answer (score 0):

You should use a double equals == instead of single = in your 'if' condition

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are actually assigning `$id` to be `=` to  `100`,

to fix that simply add a second `=` inside your `if` statment like so:

```
if ($id == 100) {echo $account;}
```

Also. I have learned to do my `if` statements like:

```
if (100 == $id) {echo $account;}
```

this simply prevents the possibility of assigning the variable and instead will cause:

> syntax error, unexpected '='

which is easier to debug